# How to include Spring Components from a dependency in Maven

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a spring boot project, "A". This contains a rest api get request called ***/helloworldA***

I have created another spring boot project "B". I have added "A" as a dependency to "B". Now I was expecting ***/helloworldA*** to work when I run project "B". But it is not working

Comment: Are the components of project "A" being loaded by the SpringBootApplication of project "B"? You probably have to tell Spring to scan the components of the packages of module "A".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should define a configuration in A.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(/**scan all beans from A**/)
public class ConfigA {

}
```

Then, in B, you should import the configuration.

```
@Configuration
@Import(ConfigA.class)
public class ConfigB {

}
```

Now the beans from A should be detected by the component scan from B.

Comment: Project A has a class called org.projecta.AppConfig

When I am trying to add this as a dependency in project "B", it says that the class is not found. But I am sure that the jar is available on the class path

Comment: That can be either a classpath issue (the jar for Project A is not found in the classpath when running project B) or you have an outdated version of the jar for Project A on the classpath.

Comment: Are you using a build tool such as `gradle` or `maven` for your build?

Comment: Finally found the issue. The Spring boot jar from "A" which I was trying to use in "B" was built by bootJar task of gradle. So the classes were having a different structure like BOOT-INF/classes/<classes>. So "B" was unable to detect the classes. For this I enabled jar task in gradle spring boot plugin. This will create a proper jar that can be used as dependency. Also I had to add a classifier to bootJar task so that the name of the jar created with bootJar task is different. Post this I used your approach to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Though @alexrolea answer is right for the issue, I also had another problem before this step.

Either maven's or gradle's spring boot plugin has 2 tasks:-
jar task/execution - This will create a jar with all the dependencies. This can be used as a dependency for other projects. But this is not an executable jar. I mean that we cannot run this jar as "java -jar "
bootJar task/execution - This runs after the jar task/execution. This will create a bootable jar. And the structure of the classes inside this jar is different. eg:- A class called com.eg.Config is located in /BOOT-INF/classes/com/eg/Config. Because of this modified structure, the other project will not be able to use this jar as dependency since the other project is unaware of this structure

My problem was that by default,

1. jar and bootJar tasks create the jars with same filename. (ie) the jar from jar task is replaced by the jar from bootJar task
2. In gradle, jar task is disabled by default. I enabled this with

   jar {
       enabled = true
   }
3. I changed the name of the jar created from bootJar task with the following

   bootJar {
       classifier = 'boot'
   }
4. Now followed the answer from @alexrolea.